# Hive script to extract month in format MMM

Tags: datetime, hive, hue

How can I extract the month from datetime value as MMM, ie. Jan? I've tried the following but not working. The error I'm getting is "AnalysisException: default.date_format() unknown for database default. Currently this db has 0 functions."

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(start_date), 'MMM') as month
from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution.
use if start_date is a date/timestamp.

```
date_format(start_date,'MMM')
```

Or, if start_date is a string date in dd-MM-yyyy format.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_date ,'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'MMM') ,
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(start_date) ,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MMM')

Answer (score 1):

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(start_date),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MMM')
```